# How to convert an HTML tree to PDF?

Tags: html, pdf, file-conversion

How to convert an HTML tree (actually [this one](http://www.flipp-explainers.org/dedication.htm)) to PDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you wish to convert HTML pages on your site to a single PDF file.

I guess the total HTML files are around 20. So rather than use a tool, you can manually open the pages in Chrome, choose the Print option & "Save as PDF". If you want to merge them into a single PDF, you can use one of the many free online or desktop [PDF merging tools](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=merge%20PDF).

Comment: I thought of going over page after page and then using PDFtk, but this sparked the more general question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Using wget (use -r for download recursive) and htmldoc for convert html tree to pdf.

```
apt-get install htmldoc
```

Answer (score 0):

[Acrobat Professional does the job](http://www.ghacks.net/2008/04/12/convert-a-full-website-into-pdf/). Haven´t found anything really freeware, that can do this.

Answer (score 0):

The most accurate and quick HTML->PDF converter I found is http://pdfcrowd.com/ 
You need to pay to a license, but it is pretty cheap. As for following the links in the PDF, you could build a simple script that would query their API.

Answer (score 0):

1.Select a conversion site, which can be found with a basic web search. Criteria for selecting a site include cost (many are free; some you must pay for), speed (some sites are faster than others), reliability (some sites are often overwhelmed with requests) and whether or not the conversion places an ad on your PDF pages.

2.Enter the website address or HTML file (if you have access to it on your computer) into the converter.

3.Convert the file to PDF.

4.Save the PDF file to your computer and check it for errors.

Answer (score 0):

For a generic solution of converting a html tree to pdf, see [this SU answer](https://superuser.com/a/219502/231052):

> I use `wget` to recursively download websites (normally online html
>   manuals) then once I have the html all in a folder I convert to the
>   format of my choice using [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/).